# What is Jquery's alternative to Mootools MochaUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, mootools

[MochaUI](http://mochaui.com/demo) is very intuitive and the modal iframes almost perfectly replicate Windows.
Unfortunately, I have scripts written in Jquery that I use, and I hear there are conflicts when putting both Mootools and Jquery on one html file (is this true?).

How can I get the MochaUI features in Jquery?

At the very least, is there a similar modal dialog system?

I've seen JqueryUI Dialog but it makes the background go dark and nonfunctional, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some tweaking (enable JQuery noConflict-Mode, replace the $ selector by something like $jq) you should be able to get to work both.

However you might easily end up with a Frankenstein app that mixes MooTools and Jquery plugins. Also the javascript load is quite enormous, because you have to include Mootools, JQuery AND their top-level UI toolkits.

I'd recommend that you investigate if JQuery UI could replace MochaUI (or vice versa). One combination of JS lib + UI toolkit is far easier to maintain.

The downside of MochaUI is that it has some issues with IE8, furthermore it is not very up-to-date (last release Sept 2008).

JQuery UI is much more modular (you can just pick the parts you need), has a visual CSS Theme Editor (Themeroller) and offers a 2-month release schedule. Its disadvantages: it doesn't yet cover essential UI components (such as a menu, a "viewport" manager that renders you UI components, palettes). However, these features are expected soon.

Comment: Update: the most recent stable version in their github is June 2010 (https://github.com/mui/mochaui/downloads), and they're still committing changes, albeit sparsely (https://github.com/mui/mochaui/commits/develop). jQuery UI still doesn't have Grid (http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/34246941/Grid), though they hope to soon have Menu (http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137997/Menu) and Panel (http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137759/Panel).

Answer (score 6):

I really love mocha-ui, and anyone who suggests jquery UI as an alternative just doesn't "get it".  Mocha-ui is smooth and beautiul, it looks professional, like a windows app in your browser.  I'm sure with css updates in the browsers it'll be very easy to accomplish what Mocha-UI already does, sadly we're not there yet.  If anyone ever does come out with a jquery plugin that has all of the functionality of mocha-UI, I hope they post it here and other places so we can all share with the goodness. :)

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

You can disable the overlay if you don't like it.

Comment: thanks. does Dialog support Iframe? or is there something similar that would do that?

Comment: I think it should work with iframes, but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use JQuery and MooTools , consult this Page :

[Using jQuery with other Libs..](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

i think you have to change the JQuery-Selector "$"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to implement the functionality done in Mootools to be applied in jQuery you can read the official jQuery documentation for using jQuery with other libraries.

[Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

If you need to do the modal dialog box in jQuery there are a lot of samples available like

[jQuery block UI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

[jQModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)

[jQuery Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this jquery plugin for layout- http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm
Jquery UI - for Modules.

However, I have not seen something close to Mocha UI. Jquery UI is so near, yet so far...

Answer (score 0):

those are things that you could use to either try and create some effects like mocha ui offers or a way to use mocha ui and jquery.  However the full featured capabilities of Mochi UI, have yet to be put together in a jquery plugin that I am aware of, despite my own search. As I am not a moo-fan in the least.